# Binary Search Tree: how to locate the "current Node" while inserting

Tags: python, data-structures

I am too stupid to ask a question. A lot of literature mentioned that we need to compare the to-insert value with the value of "current Node".

So basically, my question is:

In order to insert a new Node into a tree, we need to enter a Node. Firstly, the tree has to check whether this Node is in it. If yes, then we need to enter a value, which will be compared and then inserted.

```
class BTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
    def isEmpty(self):
        if not self.root:
            print('tree is empty')
            return self.root
    def insert(self, Node, data):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            print('the tree is empty, now is inserting ROOT')
            self.root = Node(data)
        else:
            current = self.root
            parent = None
            while True:
               #search the Node in the tree#
               #if it is in the tree, insert#
```

It is too complicated, isn't it? Because we need even implement the search algorithm in the while loop.

Could you please give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: you mean binary tree right?

Comment: you should learn about the structure of a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)

Comment: what do you mean by `'check whether this Node is in it'`? Isn't the data stored an unique identifier to the node already?

Comment: @DebanikDawn, if we want to insert a value in a tree, we need to know where to insert it right? My point is that we locate the current Node first, and then insert this new value below the current Node.

Comment: By any chance do you mean a Binary **Search** Tree?
Because in a simple Binary Tree, you can just append the new node to any leaf node.

Comment: @DebanikDawn, could be. Binary Tree is always ordered, isn't it?

Comment: Binary tree simply means a tree where each node can have at most two children. That's it.

Comment: If your question is about a Binary Search Tree, then edit the question to so.

Comment: @DebanikDawn changed.